# Keras: EarlyStopping save best model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

When I use `EarlyStopping` callback does Keras save best model in terms of `val_loss` or it save model on save_epoch = [best epoch in terms of `val_loss`] + YEARLY_STOPPING_PATIENCE_EPOCHS ?

If it's second option, how to just save best model?

Here is code snippet:

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=YEARLY_STOPPING_PATIENCE_EPOCHS)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=100, # 1 epoch = BATCH_SIZE * steps_per_epoch samples
    epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=20,
    callbacks=[early_stopping])

#Save train log to .csv
pd.DataFrame(history.history).to_csv('vgg16_binary_crossentropy_train_log.csv', index=False)

model.save('vgg16_binary_crossentropy.h5')
```

Answer (score 3):

In v2.2.4+ of Keras, [EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) has a `restore_best_weights` parameter which, when set to `True`, will set the model to the state of best CV performance. For example:

```
EarlyStopping(restore_best_weights=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience using the 'earlystopping' callback, the model will not be saved automatically...it will just stop training and when you save it manually, it will be the second option you present.
To have your model save each time val_loss decreases, see the following documentation page:
https://keras.io/callbacks/ and look at the "Example: model checkpoints" section which will tell you exactly what to do.

note that if you wish to re-use your saved model, I have had better luck using 'save_weights' in combo with saving the architecture in json. YMMV.